# set background color of different portions of a plot with different colors jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, flot, jqplot

i want to set the background color of portions of a graph with diffrent colors. and also to be able to make the axis ticks also clickable particularly for  jqplot and flot. i have been able to do that with highcharts. you can have a look at what i did : http://jsfiddle.net/fonpah/jPrvK/4/ . i would really appreciate it if anyone can do thesame thing with jqplot or flot.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

flot makes the canvas available to you, so you can easily translate your code from your high-charts example to there.

```
var plot = $.plot(...);
var ctx = plot.getCanvas().getContext("2d"); //get the canvas

var point1 = plot.pointOffset({ x: 5, y: 5}); //translate a value to pixels
var point2 = plot.pointOffset({ x: 10, y: 10}); 

//fill and draw a rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
ctx.fillRect(point1.x,point1.y,point2.x,point2.y);
```

See the [annotating example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/annotating.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

With Flot, it's very easy to draw fill area using the {fill=true} option e.g.:

lines: { show: true, fill: true, fillColor: "#98FB98" },